# Change the XML Serializer's element name of an array element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a class which is generated from an XML file via the XSD.exe tool.  The class I have contains an array with elements.

Until recently, rendering the whole document from a fully instantiated business object was possible, however due to the size, we now need to render the documents array elements to a stream so that we don't run out of memory.

However when you render the array elements you get a different element name in the XML serialization.  I tried to create an `XMLAttributesOverride` but this returned me an error stating that I could not override the `XmlElement` attributes on this property.  I am trying to keep this strongly typed and correlated to my XSD, so if anyone knows how to change the name of the XML elements to their array name +1 answer for you.

Comment: You should be able to use overrides.  Show the code you used that generated an error.

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried using the XmlArray and XmlArrayElement attributes?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx

```
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="GenericItem", Type = typeof(Item))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="BookItem", Type = typeof(BookItem))]
[XmlArray]
public Item []Items {...}
```

Comment: Problem is that the XML schema isn't controlled by me.  Therefore I'm trying to avoid editing code in the class if possible.

Answer (score 8):

Try this :)

```
[XmlType(TypeName="MyItems")]
public class MyItems:List<Item>
{   }
```

The result xml is:

```
<MyItems xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Item>...</Item>
</MyItems>
```